# how to hold the state of a checkbox and data of a textareafield in sencha touch 2.0?

Tags: android, checkbox, textarea, sencha-touch-2

I am developing an app in sencha touch 2.0.I need to know that how can i hold the state of a checkbox between the screens and how can i hold the value of text in textareafield when i go to back screen and get back again on the textareafield screen.

Let's have an example,I have two screens A and B.In screen A i have some labels and a button.In screen B i have a checkbox and a textareafield,now i want that in screen B when i check the checkbox and type some lines in textareafield and get to screen A through back button.When i get back to screen B i want that checkbox remain check and also textareafield hold the same text which i typed earlier.

Please suggest how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the easiest but **recommended** way to achieve what you need is simply store their contents into a `Ext.data.Model` instance or `Ext.data.Store`.

It might be a little bit like killing a chicken with rocket, but it best fits Sencha Touch. Somehow you can use global variables just like pure Javascript but it's a bad practice. Just treat them as normal Sencha Touch data instance.

Comment: hey Thiem i get to know that store does not work with checkboxfield to prove this i tried to apply the approach suggested by you, but i have failed to do so.Can you suggest me something else which come up to ur mind to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Store is a little crazy to store just one value. Instead you should use the browsers `localStorage` object:

```
// get the value of the checkbox and set it in local storage
localStorage.setItem('my-checkbox', checkbox.getValue());

// set the value when the checkbox is visible after reload
checkbox.setValue(localStorage.getItem('my-checkbox'));
```

More information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage